# the characteristic of the irreducible R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

As we know, if $M$ is an irreducible R-module, then $End_R(M)$ has the property that any nonzero element of it is invertible.

what about the reverse？

if $End_R(M)$ has the property that any nonzero element of it is invertible, is M irreducible,or not?

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: I only know in the case of artinian $K-$algebra case. Then $M$ is irreducible iff $End_R(M)$ is local.

Comment: i find this.https://mathoverflow.net/q/2328

Comment: My bad. In Pierce associative algebra, it says over artinian $K-$algebra $M$ indecomposable iff $End_R(M)$ is local. I guess I am confused between your irreducible(=simple) with indecomposable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s well-known that the converse is not true.  I’m sure this is mentioned in many noncommutative algebra texts.  Perhaps it is a matter of using different terminology.  You should definitely prefer “invertible” to “reversible”, and know that “irreducible” is often called “simple” nowadays.

See for example [Gangyong Lee, Cosmin S. Roman & Xiaoxiang Zhang (2014) Modules Whose Endomorphism Rings are Division Rings, Communications in Algebra, 42:12, 5205-5223, DOI: 10.1080/00927872.2013.836211](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927872.2013.836211)